# Does Poco have its own additional exception class or patterns?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, poco-libraries

Poco is designed as a foundational framework. Does it have any own additional exception class or pattern which is expected overall framework?

Comment: http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Exception.html

Comment: What do you mean by "its own pattern"?

Comment: @jogojapan Just anything which is not conventional C++ but only exist on Poco about exception handling.

Comment: @jogojapan Should I use the `Poco.Exception` class for Poco framework application?

Comment: That class is clearly the base class for poco exceptions. There is a whole hierarchy of derived exceptions (as detailed on the documentation page). As for exception handling patterns.. I don't know. This is a fairly broad question....

Answer (score 1):

Poco has it's own exception hierarchy inheriting from std::exception, with [Poco::Exception](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Exception.html) at the top. See [Error Handling and Debugging](http://pocoproject.org/slides/020-ErrorHandlingAndDebugging.pdf) for details.